# Formatting datetime field in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a field in a gridvie that displays the date in the following format

```
1/2/2012 3:45:13 AM
```

How can I format it so that it does ot show the seconds?

Thank you

```
   <telerik:GridBoundColumn 
    DataField="AdmissionDate" 
    HeaderText="Date" 
    SortExpression="AdmissionDate"
              HtmlEncode="False" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(short date and short time):

```
DataFormatString="{0:g}"
```

Although this is for `BoundFields` in an ASP.NET `GridView`, i assume(i have no experiences with Telerik controls) that it works also on a Telerik GridBoundColumn, because [it also has this property](http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/radgrid.net2-telerik.webcontrols.gridboundcolumn-dataformatstring.html).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn
        DataField="AdmissionDate"
        DataType="System.DateTime"
        HeaderText="AdmissionDate"
        SortExpression="OrderDate"
        DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mm}"
        UniqueName="AdmissionDate">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a Property on your BusinessObject called AdmissionDateDisplay that is a string and use a format string from the web.config to format your date as you want it and Display it in the DataField.

Or you could take a look at their demo on formating columns [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/columnformatting/defaultcs.aspx)